# Can Jakarta and javax JAXB packages co-exist in the same project?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have two libraries in my project:

- Library A depends on the old XML bind libraries `javax.xml.bind...`
- Library B depends on the new XML bind libraries `jakarta.xml.bind...`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
  <version>x</version>
</dependency>
```

If version x=2.3.x library B breaks. If x=4.0.x A breaks (with class not found exceptions).

Is there a way for new and old binding APIs to coexist in the classpath? If so, which depedencies shall I use? If not, is shading the only solution?

Runtime used:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldnt try to make it work as-is since you might encounter other problems at runtime.

I'd suggest you use eclipse transformer to make the javax dependency being transformed in a jakarta one (see for example [this guide](https://omnifish.ee/2023/08/04/upgrade-to-jakarta-ee-10-transform-incompatible-dependencies/))

If you really want to try make it run, you should use older maven coordinates for jaxb2.3 like the api

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And make jakarta ones beeing jakarta based.